# How to add random strings alphabetically to an array using a Bi-Sectional Search

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my add function. I haven't finished it yet, I have to add strings into the array using sequential search to find the insertion point to add in alphabetical order. I just included this b/c we use it when we add random strings.

```
void StringList::add(string s) 
{
    str[numberOfStrings++]=s;       
}
```

This is my bisectional search function

```
int StringList::bsearch(string key, int start, int end)
{
    int middle = (end + start)/2;
if(key>str[middle])
{
    return bsearch(key, middle+1, end);
}
else if (key<str[middle])
{
    return bsearch(key, start, middle);
}
else if(start==end)
{
    return -1;
}
}
```

Here is my code to add a random number of strings to the array. (In a seperate cpp file that uses a transducer)

```
if((token[0]=="ADDRAND")||(token[0]=="AR"))
{
    int count = stringToInt(token[1]);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        stringList.add(randString(20));
    }
    result = "Random Strings added.\n";

}
```

How do I use the Bi-sectional search to add the random strings to the array in alphabetical order using this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to modify your bsearch() so that it may return the index where to insert the string if not found (a good start may be returning `start` instead of `-1`, but I don't know if it's enough).

Answer (score 0):

If even you are able to find the index where to insert, you have to push all the elements after that index by a step to make place for that string. So this will take linear time for each step. I don't think you would be able to use your bi-sectional search method to dynamically update array and keep it sorted. Either insertion of string in array or searching of index will take time if you try to keep sorted strings in contiguous string indices.

For this purpose, you need to use some tree structure such as AVL Tree or RB tree. Moreover stl set can serve the purpose if you need readymade structure.